# Focus option without select the value in the option list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I have a requirement which is based on open a "Select" with a lot of options but it should start the selection in the half of the list without select that value in which the component was started

```
<select> 
   <option value="1">value 1</option> 
   <option value="2">value 2</option> 
   <option value="3">value 3</option> 
   <option value="4">value 4</option> 
   <option value="5">value 5</option> 
   <option value="6">value 6</option>
   <option value="7">value 7</option> 
   <option value="8">value 8</option> 
   <option value="9">value 9</option> 
   <option value="10">value 10</option>
```

When the user opens the list it should start in the middle without select that option, see how the middle option is just focused but not selected:

[image]

It's there any way to achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: Not really with a `<select>` . You can fake it with CSS style on the middle option but you can't use events on `<option>` tag and there is no event on the select to detect that it is being opened. That's why there are numerous select replacement scripts that use other html lists for display

Comment: Do you mean when the dropdown opens?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: Styling `<select>` is tricky business. Tested in Chrome, FF, Edge, Windows10

```js
document.querySelectorAll("select[size]").forEach(EL => {
  
  const h = EL.scrollHeight / EL.options.length; // option height
  const i = Math.floor(EL.options.length / 2); // Index of the half-way option
  const s = Math.floor(EL.size / 2); // Get the size (also half-way)
  
  EL.options[i].classList.add("highlight"); // (PS: this is bad UX)
  EL.scroll(0, h * (i - s));
});
```

```css
select option.highlight {
  background: #0bf;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<select size="3">
  <option value="1">value 1</option>
  <option value="2">value 2</option>
  <option value="3">value 3</option>
  <option value="4">value 4</option>
  <option value="5">value 5</option>
  <option value="6">value 6</option>
  <option value="7">value 7</option>
  <option value="8">value 8</option>
  <option value="9">value 9</option>
  <option value="10">value 10</option>
</select>
```

NOTE: The CSS-`.highlight` option might be a really bad UI and lead to people thinking that that option is actually **`selected`** while it's clearly **not**.
Avoid doing stuff that users are not used to see in the web world.

Therefore: instead of doing

```
EL.options[i].classList.add("highlight"); // (PS: this is bad UX)
```

**rather do:**

```
EL.options[i].selected = true;
```

Comment: I'm agreed that is bad UX putting that style instead of select the element, how i can autoscroll the list to be open in the middle?

Comment: @EdgardoRodriguez it's not scrolling already on your machine? Are you on Windows? Chrome? Have you noticed `EL.scroll(0, h * (i - s));` ? It's used exactly for that purpose.

Comment: @EdgardoRodriguez when you RUN the above demo, the select box is not scrolled showing "value 6" in the middle?

Comment: @RokoBuljan If I take out the size attribute in the select when it doesn't scroll when I open the list.

Comment: @EdgardoRodriguez well, you removed the `size` attribute in one of your edits https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62784857/revisions - making this answer pretty much obsolete

Comment: @EdgardoRodriguez I don't think there's a way to handle the OS scrollable widget with the options. (Not without having the `size=""` attribute you removed.)